# Unable to create LaTex documentation with haddock/cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal, haddock

I'm trying to generate LaTex-documantation for my project with Haddock.
Everything is build with `cabal` (... `cabal configure` and `cabal build` work without a problem). Everything works fine for the html-version of the documentation.

But when I issue `cabal haddock --haddock-option=--latex` it still builds the html:

```
Documentation created: dist/doc/html/my_project/index.html
Preprocessing executable 'my_project' for my_project-0.1.0.0..
```

I get some `*.tex` files dumped in the `dist/doc/html/my_project/` folder. The generated output seems broken: trying to build `my_project.tex` with `pdflatex` results in a slew of error messages.

```
...
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> ...egin \relax \d@llarend \endtemplate 

l.60 \end{tabulary}
               \par
```

Am I missing something important? And is that the usual way - that I have to build the documentation from `tex`-files by hand (or script)?

Comment: it would help if you gave the exact tool versions (cabal, haddock, ghc), and the output of your command  when run with some extra `-v`.

Comment: The LaTeX backend is pretty much unmaintained. You should report problems with its output on the issue tracker.